# R add a legend to a france map

Tags: r, maps, legend

Hi I just want to add a legend to this map which represents the fecundity of young women by departments in France :
[image]

With this code :

```
library(raster)

fr <- getData(country='France',level=2)

classes <- c('0-1','1-1.5','1.5-2','2-3')

fr$fertility <- sample(seq(1,3,0.1),length(fr),replace = T)

fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility <=1] <-1 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 1 & fr$fertility <=1.5] <-2 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 1.5 & fr$fertility <=2] <-3 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 2 & fr$fertility <=3] <- 4 

fr$cols <- c('red','orange','yellow','green')[fr$fertgroups]

plot(fr,col=fr$cols)
```

I dont know how to add that legend.

Comment: Have a look at function `legend`.

Comment: legend(LON,LAT, legend=classes,fill=fr$cols)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
plot(fr, col=fr$cols)
legend("topright", as.character(unique(fr$fertgroups)), fill = unique(fr$cols))
```

[image]

Comment: do share (as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
locator(n=1)
legend(-6.780717,45.01717,legend=classes,
fill=fr$cols, cex=0.6, bty="n")
```

[image]